# Karate - actual value is not a string

Tags: karate

I am checking for an 'OK' parameter in response but getting above mentioned error. The same code was working with my previous karate version, now I am using 0.9.0 - This might be some issue with my coding, can't figure out.

Response:

```
"testResponse": {
    "planSummary": {
      "includedServicesList": [
          {
            "some elements goes here": "test"
          }
        ],
      "status": {
        "statusCd": "200",
        "statusTxt": "OK"
      }
   }
}
```

My Feature File Code:

```
When method get
Then status 200
Then match response contains 'OK'
```

I get `expected: 'OK', reason: actual value is not a string` error.

I tried with `Then match response contains {statusTxt: 'OK'}` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this,

```
* match response.testResponse.planSummary.status contains {'statusTxt' : 'OK'}
```

**OR**

```
* match response.testResponse.planSummary.status.statusTxt == 'OK'
```